# How to save Quill.js Delta in DynamoDB

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, quill

I'm quite new using DynamoDB and Quills.

I want to use Quills Deltas to create and display text/images on a website, but I haven't found any documentation regarding the implementation of Quills Deltas using DynamoDB.

How should I add to my graghQl schema? Also, I would like to save the embedded images into an S3 bucket instead of using the default encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reading, I came into the realization that you can just use `JSON.stringify()` save the String into DynamoDB and `JSON.parse()` when using it.

Comment: It looks like you’re new to StackOverflow—welcome! Since you found an answer that works, you should accept that answer (even though it’s your own) because it will help other people who may have a similar question.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I will do so in the future, tought it could be interpreted as rep farming